# Sharing permissions of the copy of a script is still linked to the original

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing code on Google Apps Script for an organisation that I want to keep a copy of just in case. So I made a copy of the Script file, transferred the ownership from the organisation to myself, then removed the organisation. But then I realised the exact changes happened for the original Script.

Why is this so? How do I un-link the copy and the original? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you made the changes to the correct file? Or did you change the sharing settings with a script? Did anyone else have access to the file? Copies do not keep the same sharing settings so something else must have happened. Normally you'd just share the original with your account, then when you make a copy, the copy is created with you as the sole owner.

Comment: The easiest way to share scripts is to put them in a shared drive and give other users full access.  They will be able to take anything out and it's all theirs.

Comment: @Daniel yes, I was absolutely sure that I made the changes to the correct file, I did it multiple times because I couldn’t believe that they seemed to be linked. I also do not have any scripts that could automatically changed sharing permissions. When I made a copy of the script from my own account, it created a copy with the original owner as the owner.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this? Either with the same files or with different ones? For me, making a copy always puts the new file under my name.

Comment: @Daniel it happened with two different files, so i guess it’s reproducible for me…? Are your scripts linked to other documents like sheets or forms?